# Deserialize CSV with ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, csv, servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm trying to use ServiceStack.Text for deserializing a csv file containing ";" as the seperator.

The test csv contains this data

```
---------------
| Col1 | Col2 |
---------------
| Val1 | Val2 |
---------------
| Val3 | Val4 |
---------------

public class Line
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
}
```

The code that works:

```
var CsvWithComma = "Col1,Col2" + Environment.NewLine + 
"Val1,Val2" + Environment.NewLine +
"Val3,Val3" + Environment.NewLine;

var r1 = ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<Line>>(CsvWithComma);

Assert.That(r1.Count() == 2, "It should be 2 rows");
Assert.That(r1[0].Col1 == "Val1", "Expected Val1");
Assert.That(r1[0].Col2 == "Val2", "Expected Val2");
```

The code that fails:

```
ServiceStack.Text.CsvConfig.ItemSeperatorString = ";";

var CsvWithSemicolon = "Col1;Col2" + Environment.NewLine +
"Val1;Val2" + Environment.NewLine +
"Val3;Val3" + Environment.NewLine;

var r2 = ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<Line>>(CsvWithSemicolon);

Assert.That(r2.Count() == 2, "It should be 2 rows");
Assert.That(r2[0].Col1 == "Val1", "Expected Val1");
Assert.That(r2[0].Col2 == "Val2", "Expected Val2");
```

When I dig into the ServiceStack code is seems like it's using the ServiceStack.Text.Common.JsWriter.ItemSeperator as a seperator for the CSV reader and not the ServiceStack.Text.CsvConfig.ItemSeperatorString.

Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be supported from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/8d8829098aa2f8ef37e409f98619660fa5d0c11e).

This change is available from v4.0.57+ that's now [available from MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).