# In C#, can a Salesforce Report "CSV" be deserialized to a C# Object?

Tags: c#, csv, object, salesforce, deserialization

We will receive Salesforce Reports in "CSV" format via a REST/POST endpoint, where it will be captured as an instance of `IFormFile`, which we can turn to a Stream with `file.OpenReadStream()`.

While allegedly comma separated, they are actually semi-colon separated and to further reduce the risk of ambiguity, all values are surrounded by quotes.  Not least, the headers are intended to be human readable, so unlike variable names they contain spaces.

A typical file might look like this:

```
"Opportunity Name";"Order Number";"Date of request for deed registry check";"Date of deed registry evaluation"
"Implementation - Jayde Cote";"20190605_Cote_11";"";"09.11.2020"
"Implementation - Ebony Collier";"20190612_Collier_48";"09.10.2020";"09.11.2020"
"Implementation - Izzy Bains";"20190528_Bains_42";"09.11.2020";""
```

I'd like to deserialize this into a List where Opportunity is a class like:

```
public class Opportunity {
    public string OpportunityName {get; set;}
    public string OrderNumber {get; set;}
    public DateTime RequestDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime EvaluationDate {get; set;}
}
```

Yes, I know I could build a parser for this, but deserializing would be more elegant.
Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: There are 3rd Party libraries (such as CSVHelper) which will generate objects and `IEnumerable<T>` from the CSV with all the elegance and grace as your proposed deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a one of the many libraries out there, for example [TinyCsvParser](https://github.com/bytefish/TinyCsvParser).
The setup is pretty straightforward, a few options to declare your requirements (" as Quote character, \ as Escape character and ; as Delimiter). I realized you are using a pretty similar format to RFC4180 so...:

```
var options = new Options('"', '\\', ';');
var tokenizer = new RFC4180Tokenizer(options);      
CsvParserOptions csvParserOptions = new CsvParserOptions(true, tokenizer);      
CsvReaderOptions   csvReaderOptions = new CsvReaderOptions(new[] { Environment.NewLine });
```

Then you need a map declaration, in your case something like this, although you can also use a TypeConverter like this one new DateTimeConverter("dd.MM.yyyy"), in your case is unnecessary:

```
private sealed class CsvOpportunityMap : CsvMapping<Opportunity>
{
    public CsvOpportunityMap() : base()
    {
        MapProperty(0, m => m.OpportunityName );
        MapProperty(1, m => m.OrderNumber );
        MapProperty(2,  m => m.RequestDate);
        MapProperty(3,  m => m.EvaluationDate);
    }
}
```

I've built an example with your scenario, I don't like the way TinyCsvParser builds the properties map but I think it's nice in terms of performance and footprint size (in memory also)

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3bXrap

Comment: Cheers for putrting the work into this.  If I _need_ to parse, this seems a good way to go.... but I'm hoping to find either a way to use ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer or something much like it to do all the work and not have to worry about columns getting shifted around.  Something like this:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844632/deserialize-csv-with-servicestack-text ... but able to work with my CSV.